# What affects the artifacts granted by the Lutefisk God?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

Often after a bout of Skol!-ing, the artifact I receive from tithing lutefisk to the Lutefisk God is a little underwhelming.  I'm wondering what I can do (if anything) to influence the "quality" of the item (as measured in stars, if not actual usefulness).

In particular I'd like to know if the following have any affect on the outcome:

- Dungeon level that the statue resides on (probably makes sense, for balance reasons)
- Character level
- Amount of lutefisk tithed
- Anything else (e.g. existing artifacts carried - unlikely I suspect)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What artefact you receive is random, but giving more Lutefisk can result in extra enchantments.

Specifically, each 125 Lutefisk added to the statue for one object will grant an extra enchantment on the artefact received. So, 500 Lutefisk for an object will grant the best possible results of four extra enchantments.

Given there is a % chance of getting an artefact each time you give Lutefisk to a statue, the way to get the best possible object is to drop 500 Lutefisk in one go on to an empty statue (or whatever quantity you need to make the current total 500). As well as giving the maximum possible number of extra enchantments, this will also ensure a 100% chance of receiving an artefact.

See the [Lutefisk Statue](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Lutefisk_Statue) page on the wiki for more information

Comment: OK - so it seems that the base item is arbitrary, but I can help maximise the number of enchantments on it.  Thanks.

Comment: But according to the source you linked it's 125 lutefisk/enchantment and 0.2% per lutefisk for artifact, so 500 should be the optimal number...

Comment: @oak yeah looks like it changed in September - http://www.dredmorwiki.com/w/index.php?title=Lutefisk_Statue&action=historysubmit&diff=11648&oldid=10356 n will update answer when I'm home later