# What does giving lutefisk to the lutefisk god actually do?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

As in the title. Do I get anything out of it, or is it pointless?

Comment: Probably makes them gag. Look up the food dish [Lutefisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lutefisk) sometime, it's disgusting.

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/26917/what-affects-the-artifacts-granted-by-the-lutefisk-god

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you tithe enough pieces, you get an artifact you can use or sell.

From the [wiki](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Lutefisk_Statue):

> Each Lutefisk tithed increases the chance of receiving a random reward (each Lutefisk increases the chance of obtaining an artifact by 0.2%, up to 100%).

You can sell to the shopkeeper three ways:

1. Click on the item in your inventory and then drop it onto him.
2. Click on the item in your inventory and then drop it onto an available space in the shop.
3. Hold down shift while in a shop to enable quick-sell mode.  Then click on the item in your inventory. It will be sold immediately without telling you how much you will get or confirming the sale, so be careful.

Comment: Sell? How? Can I only sell using the archaeologist skill This Belongs In A Museum, or is there another way? And do I get an artifact every 30 or so pieces, or just the one time?

Comment: I thought you could sell to the shopkeeper guy (haven't played Dredmor in a while..damn you Skyrim).

Comment: I still haven't found a way to sell to the shopkeeper...I know I can try and steal an item from him, but I don't know how to sell.

Comment: @OddCore I believe you drag items onto him.

Comment: @OddCore The shopkeeper needs to have a space available tho, so you need to buy an item then sell it.

Comment: The quote from the wiki is a little confusing. Each Lutefisk increases the chance by 0.2%, that's fine, but when is that chance rolled for? If I take a stack of 100 lutefisk and drop it onto the statue, does it just roll for a 20% chance, or does it roll once for each lutefisk with increasing chance (so it would roll for 0.2%, then for 0.4%, then for 0.6% ... up to 20%)? Obviously the difference is huge.